# How to create gui in C++

Tags: c++

I'm new in C++ and looking for a way to create gui just like windowbuilder under eclipse (java).
I will appreciate if someone can help me to find tool like windowbuilder.
OS : Linux

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO. Questions asking about recommendations for tools are off-topic for this forum. Please try searching online as there are a plethora of resources discussing this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I'm a fan of [Qt](http://www.qt.io/).

However, it depends entirely on what you want to do.  Qt is primarily for cross platform development, so it'll look and act mostly the same between any platform, it also has a large library that may require a bit of a learning curve at first - but the licencing options make it look pretty.  Also the documentation is very awesome.

There are of course a lot of other options like:
GTKmm (based on GTK+), wxWidgets, FLTK, etc...

Also this is a duplicate question, so look at some of these other answers:

[How do I create a GUI for a windows application using C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488837/how-do-i-create-a-gui-for-a-windows-application-using-c)

[How do I build a GUI in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1186017/how-do-i-build-a-gui-in-c)

Comment: Thank you for your reply "Darth Futuza". I'm using Eclipse under Ubuntu and want to create graph to plot may data/values with some buttons and labels etc

Comment: QT designer seems to be a good option

Comment: If you are wanting to plot a graph, afaik Qt doesn't have a built in function for that - however there are plug-ins for Qt that do support it.  One example is here: http://www.qcustomplot.com/