# How C++ resource script works?

Tags: visual-c++

How is the internal linking process of the resource file in VC++ 6.0? 
or better yet, if anyone can give a good example of how i can emulate
the standard code from Win32 Application without a resource script. 
I mean, include accelerator table, menu, dialog box and icon. Just using code C++.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows API Dialogs without using resource files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61634/windows-api-dialogs-without-using-resource-files)

Comment: There's plenty of documentation on MSDN to do most of this, you just need to search.  As far as icons, you'll need to convert the file to an array of bytes yourself.  I gotta ask, why?

Comment: Thank you. the point is I don't wanna work with visual studio, just develop c++ using my own tools, is more a compiler theory question, i just wanna learn raw C++.

Comment: Interesting the only tag you picked was `visual-c++` if you don't want to use it.  The information on MSDN describes the Windows API and what it expects from code, there's no need to be tied to a particular compiler.

Comment: Yes you're right I must be more accurate the next time. But this RC compiler or windres compiler (in case of working with mingw) are standars??? or just a programming good practice?